# How does printf work in this program to convert a decimal into binary?

Tags: c

I came across this program to convert decimals numbers into their binary equivalent in C. I do not understand how the printf statement works in this program.

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N); // Enter decimal equivalent here
    for( int j = floor(log2(N)); j >= 0; j-- ){
        printf("%d", (N >> j) & 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell you that it is doing whatever it is doing in a *very bad way*. So you better ask how to do something rather to try to understand how some weirdo did it before.

Comment: You know if you just write it out by hand and google what the operators >> and & do and go through the for loop logic, you will understand.

Comment: I am confused on the & 1, anything & 1 is itself

Comment: @OmidCompSCI No, it is not. It is masking the LSB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well im talking about a single bit anded with 1, of course if you and by FFFF or whatever then all bits would be the same

Comment: @OmidCompSCI `N >> j` is not a single bit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i understand, in this case it doesn't become itself. But anything same # of bits & with same # of 1 is itself.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI So what don't you understand? The purpose of it is to keep the right-most bit value only.

Comment: I understand it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, its better to skip this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example to get through this problem. Suppose you enter N=65. Its binary representation is - 1000001. When your given code goes through it, j will start at floor(log2(65)), which is 6. So, the given loop will run 7 times, which means 7 numbers will be printed out (which fits the fact that 65's binary representation has 7 digits).

Inside the loop - The number is shifted by j bits each time to the right. When 1000001 is shifted to the right by 6 bits, it becomes 0000001. If shifted by 5, it is 0000010, and so on. It goes down to a shift by 0 bits which is the original number. When each of these shifted numbers are &ed with 1, only the least significant bit (the right most bit) remains. And this digit can either be a 0 or a 1.

If you would have noticed each right shift divides the number by 2. So when 1000001 is shifted by 1 to make 0100000, it is the binary representation of 32, which indeed is 65/2 in C. After all, this is the way someone manually calculates the binary representation of a number. Each division by 2 gives you a digit (starting from the end) of the representation, and that digit is either a 0 or a 1. The & helps in getting the 0 or 1.

In the end, 65 becomes 1000001.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i do not understand where the actual conversion(decimal to binary) is taking place in this program? You have written "Inside the loop - The number is shifted by j bits each time to the right. ". Which number are you talking about in this statement? And if the number here is binary equivalent of the decimal number where did its conversion took place?

Comment: Okay. Now i get it. No need to reply for my earlier comment. Your explanation made everything clear.

Answer (score 1):

What it is doing is:

- Finding the largest number `j` such that `2^j <= N`
- Starting at the `j`th bit (counting from the right) and moving to the right ...

  - chopping off all of the bits to the right of the current chosen bit
  - chopping off all of the bits to the left of current chosen bit
  - printing the value of the single remaining bit

Comment: Thanks. Now i understand whats happening in this code. Another elaborate answer made everything clear.

Answer (score 0):

The code actually has undefined behavior because you did not include `<stdio.h>`, nor `<math.h>`. Without a proper declaration of `floor()` and `log2()`, the compiler infers the prototype from the calling context and gets `int log2(int)` and `int floor(int)`, which is incompatible with the actual definition in the C library.

With the proper includes, `log2(N)` gives the logarithm of `N` in base 2. Its integral part is the power of 2 <= `N`, hence 1 less than the number of bits in `N`.

Note however that this method does not work for negative values of `N` and only works by coincidence for `0` as the conversion of `NaN` to `int` gives `0`, hence a single binary digit.